# Band at the bottom and the top of the screen of my React-native application

Tags: react-native

I'm creating an application using React-native but I have a problem. There is a band at the bottom and at the top of the screen. I think that the "ScreenBase" element is the cause of this mistake, but I can't remove it because it's very important.

[Here is a screenshot of my application. You can see the band at the top and at the bottom.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxOlj.png)

Here the code of my screen :

```
return(
        <ScreenBase style={styles.container}>
            <ScrollView>
                <View style={styles.field}>
                    <Text style={styles.fieldName}>{t('contact')} : </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.fieldValue}>{inventory.contact}</Text>
                </View>
                {isModified && <View style={styles.field}>
                    <Button
                        title={t('uploadToServer')}
                        buttonStyle={[styles.syncBtn]}
                        containerStyle={styles.syncBtnContainer}
                        titleStyle={{ color: styles.syncBtn.color }}
                        onPress={syncSelfToServer}
                        icon={
                            {
                                name:'cloud-upload',
                                type:'font-awesome',
                                color:styles.syncBtn.color,
                                style: {paddingLeft: 5}
                            }
                        }
                        iconRight={true}
                    />
                </View>}
                <View style={styles.field}>
                    <Text style={styles.fieldName}>{t('lotsPlural')} : </Text>
                    <View style={styles.pictureList}>
                        {/* <TouchableOpacity
                            style={styles.pictureBtn}
                            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('LotForm', {pId: inventory.id})}
                        >
                            <Icon
                                name='plus'
                                type='font-awesome'
                                color={styles.pictureBtn.color}
                                style={styles.icon}
                                size={100}
                            />                
                            <Text style={styles.pictureTitle}>{t('addLot')}</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity> */}

                        {displayedLots}
                    </View>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>

            {/* BUTTON TO ADD A LOT */}
            <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.button, styles.addLotBtn]} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('LotForm', {pId: inventory.id})}>
                <Icon
                        name='plus'
                        type='font-awesome'
                        color={styles.iconAdd.color}
                        style={styles.iconAdd}
                        size={styles.iconAdd.fontSize}
                />
            </TouchableOpacity>
                    
        </ScreenBase>
    )
```

Do you have a solution to resolve my problem please ?

Thank you !

I tried to remove the ScreenBase element. It works but it's a bad practice because this element is very important.

Comment: Is it fixed height?

Comment: ScreenBase have a minHeight of 100%

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved my problem by adding **overflow: 'visible'** to the **ScrollView**.